# Getting caller class name for Formatter [Java Logging with File Handler]

Tags: java, class, logging, formatting, filehandler

I want to add a FileHandler to my logger. And I am also creating a new Formatter(java.util.logging.Formatter) for my FileHandler

In the format method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord), is it possible to get the class which called the log https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log(java.util.logging.Level,%20java.lang.String)method?

Edit: I wrapped my logger in a class, so getSourceClassName() will not work

Comment: sure. Use a stack(trace), or, pass it to the logger as parameter.

Comment: I can't pass it to the logger as parameters because im calling addHandler on a logger from a library

Comment: How would you use a stack trace

Comment: read the stacktrace, and get the 2nd StackElement (I think it's the second) and get the class from that element

Comment: If you mean Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() or any other stack trace. Im trying to avoid them because they are inefficient and expensive

Comment: Typically the loggers are named after the class they're logging - eg. private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.wombat.nose");      In this case, you should be able to use logRecord.getLoggerName().

Comment: Im trying to get the class which called the log method

Comment: @IanLim which is what racraman is talking about.

Comment: @racraman true, but not always the case

Comment: @Stultuske in my case, it is not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...is it possible to get the class which called the log? Note that LogRecord.getSourceClassName() returns the Logger class.

`LogRecord.getSourceClassName()` does exactly what you want it to do.  Here is an example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileHandlerTest {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("tester");

    static {
        try {
            FileHandler h = new FileHandler();
            logger.addHandler(h);
            h.setFormatter(new TestFormatter());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    private static class TestFormatter extends Formatter {

        @Override
        public String format(LogRecord record) {
            return record.getSourceClassName();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new File(".").getCanonicalPath());
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "This not a test. This is the real thing!");
    }
}
```

When I run this on my machine it creates a file called `java0.log` in my user home containing the text `FileHandlerTest` which is the name of the source class.

There are a few reason I can think as to why it wouldn't work:

1. There was a hand off to another thread and you didn't call `LogRecord.getSourceClassName()` before the hand off.  This causes the log record to infer the wrong caller.
2. You created a 'wrapper' class to perform your logging and the logger reports the 'wrapper' class as the caller.  **Don't do this.** Use the logger directly or use a logging framework.  There are plenty of logging bridges out there and anything you will create is going to be a pirate ship plank.  That said, the [com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger.java) contains the code that all of the user comments have been trying to explain to you.
3. The record was generated with `logp` or `setSourceClassName` and the source class was faked.
4. There was a problem with your JVM generating exceptions with stack traces.

You need to include more source code and example log file output data.

Comment: My whole project is sharing the same logger

Comment: @IanLim So does my project above and it functions.  Include a test case that mimics the project and reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oops I didnt noticed my library had wrapped my logger. What to do??

Comment: @IanLim  The short answer is don't wrap the logger.  I've updated the answer for the long version.